# Iterating through PL/SQL result in SHELL

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I want to iterate over PL/SQL rows in SHELL script and for each row I want to execute some code using current row. At this point I got:

```
    VALUE='sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
     CONNECT ${CONNECT}
       select smth from table;
        /
        EXIT
        EOF'

for i in "${VALUE[@]}"
do
##some code using "i" variable
done
```

At this point for 5 rows code executes only once. It appears it doesn't iterate at all. Any ideas how can I fix that?

Comment: either there is no data returned from the query OR something wrong inside the for loop; in which case can you update accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate your resultset as follows:

```
SQL> select car_model from available_models
  2  group by car_model ;

CAR_MODEL
------------------------------
Corsair
Executive
Country Squire

SQL>
```

Rewrite your shell script (using WHILE) as follows:

```
[oracle@ora12c 1]$ cat test.sh
CONNECT='z_test/welcome1'
VALUE=`sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
     CONNECT ${CONNECT}
     set head off
     select car_model from available_models
     group by car_model
        /
        EXIT
EOF`

echo "resultset: "
echo "${VALUE}"

echo " "

echo "now iterate ..."
let rec=0

echo "${VALUE}" |while read line
do
  echo "processing $rec: $line"
  let rec=rec+1
done

[oracle@ora12c 1]$
```

And this is the expected output:

```
[oracle@ora12c 1]$ ./test.sh
resultset:

Corsair
Executive
Country Squire

now iterate ...
processing 0:
processing 1: Corsair
processing 2: Executive
processing 3: Country Squire
```

Note that line #0 is blank and is expected, because is part of your resultset too.

Adding "set pagesize 0" will remove this blank line:

```
[oracle@ora12c 1]$ cat test.sh
CONNECT='z_test/welcome1'
VALUE=`sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
     CONNECT ${CONNECT}
     set head off
     set pagesize 0
     select car_model from available_models
     group by car_model
        /
        EXIT
EOF`
......
```

Expected run:

```
[oracle@ora12c 1]$ ./test.sh
resultset:
Corsair
Executive
Country Squire

now iterate ...
processing 0: Corsair
processing 1: Executive
processing 2: Country Squire
[oracle@ora12c 1]$
```

Regards