# Iterating through PL/SQL result in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I am new to the shell scripting hence need help. I am trying to execute sql query against Oracle DB. Once sql query result is received, I need to iterate through the result (as it will return multiple rows and columns.).

**Goal here is to invoke a REST api using curl for each record retrieved in db result. Input to REST api will be ROOT_PROC_ID column value.**

Below is the shell script I have developed so far and sample output of the sql query.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Update below properties as per enviornment
export ENV=DEV;
export SERVERHOST=localhost
export SERVERPORT=9000
export SERVERUSER=admin
export SERVERPASSWORD=admin123
export DBHOST=localhost
export DBPORT=1537
export DBSID=ORCL
export DBUSER=SCOTT
export DBPASS=TIGER
export LOGDIR=/usr/app/$USER/data/logs/

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------- DO NOT EDIT AFTER THIS LINE ---------------------------------
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

#create directory structure if not exists for storing log files
mkdir -p $LOGDIR/process_cancellation
mkdir -p $LOGDIR/process_cancellation/old
mkdir -p $LOGDIR/process_cancellation/halted
export old_proc_cancellation_logfile=$LOGDIR/process_cancellation/old/log_$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S").log;
export halted_proc_cancellation_logfile=$LOGDIR/process_cancellation/halted/log_$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S").log;

#execute sql query to fetch halted process data from database
echo
echo "Enviornment : $ENV"
echo
echo "Connecting to - $DBUSER/$DBPASS@$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBSID"
echo
echo "Retrieving halted process data logged before : $(date -d "15 days ago" +%d/%m/%Y) 20:00:00"
echo
sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASS@$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBSID << FIN_SQL > $halted_proc_cancellation_logfile
set head off
set line 1024
set pages 9999
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SELECT  ROOT_PROC_ID, PROC_ID, PROC_NAME, START_DATE, STATUS, ORDER_REF 
FROM USER.PROC_STATUS
WHERE START_DATE<(SYSDATE - 15) AND (STATUS='proc_halted' OR STATUS='proc_failed')
ORDER BY START_DATE DESC;
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF;
FIN_SQL

echo "Please check log file for more details : $(readlink -f $halted_proc_cancellation_logfile)"

exit
```

Sample SQL query output:

```
ROOT_PROC_ID    PROC_ID         PROC_NAME               START_DATE                          STATUS      ORDER_REF
pvm:0a123akpd   pvm:0a123akkh   FunctionalErrorProcess  28-NOV-19 01.24.35.115000000 PM     pi_halted   2642277 
pvm:0a122utrn   pvm:0a122uun0   TechnicalErrorProcess   22-NOV-19 02.28.17.217000000 PM     pi_halted   2642278 
pvm:0a122utl2   pvm:0a122uu1t   TechnicalErrorProcess   22-NOV-19 02.27.54.024000000 PM     pi_halted   2642279 
pvm:0a122utln   pvm:0a122uu22   TechnicalErrorProcess   22-NOV-19 02.27.50.287000000 PM     pi_halted   2642280
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? The ask is not clear

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533591/iterating-through-pl-sql-result-in-shell#answer-31546029) what you are asking for?

Comment: @Guru - Updated question with the objective. Pasting same here: "Goal here is to invoke a REST api using curl for each record retrieved in db result. Input to REST api will be ROOT_PROC_ID column value."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sql query output is in output.txt:

```
awk 'NR!=1' output.txt | while read rootprocid undef
do
   callApi $rootprocid
done
```

`NR!=1` is to skip the 1st line which contains the header.

`read rootprocid undef` reading only the 1st column in rootprocid, rest goes to variable undef since it is not of interest.

`callApi $rootprocid` callAPI will be replaced with your actual api call.

Comment: Thanks Guru. Actually, I am trying to read ROO_PROC_ID from shell script var itself to invoke REST api. Once REST api is successfully invoked, I am planning to change the status to 'pi_cancelled'. In the end, I am planning to create CSV file with DB Result where ideally status column will have either 'pi_cancelled' or 'pi_halted' values. Hope this helps to understand the complete requirement.